# How do you convert json to python function arguments?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, openai-api

I'm trying to make a program that allows anyone to use the ChatGPT API using my API key using the Official OpenAI API. I am using a Flask server to listen to requests. Here is my code:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
import openai, json

openai.api_key = API_KEY

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/v1/chat/completions', methods=["POST"])
def index():
    return openai.ChatCompletion.create(json.loads(request.get_json(force=True)))

app.run(debug=True, port=8080)
```

and here's my request body:

```json
{'model': 'gpt-3.5-turbo', 'messages': [{'role': 'user', 'content': 'What is 2 + 2?'}], 'temperature': 0}
```

There seems to be a parsing error because it says: `openai.error.InvalidRequestError: Must provide an 'engine' or 'model' parameter to create a <class 'openai.api_resources.chat_completion.ChatCompletion'>` even though in my requests I give it a model.

Comment: `request.get_json(force=True)` does LOAD into json, the call json.loads is useless and should fail normally, share `print(request.get_json(force=True))`

Comment: @azro heres the output: {'model': 'gpt-3.5-turbo', 'messages': [{'role': 'user', 'content': 'What is 2 + 2?'}], 'temperature': 0}

Comment: that **can't** be the output of get_json, if your code runs well. It that was you would have a JsonDecodeError 100%, share `request.text` please

Comment: `Must provide an 'engine' or 'model' parameter` - You gave it a dict

Comment: @azro request.text is the same as request.json

Comment: @OneCricketeer please show in an answer how I gave it a dict as I don't understand

Comment: How do you call your API ? please edit your post and share that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert one string into multiple parameters. Plus, as mentioned in the comments, you don't need `json.loads` as `request.get_json()` should return what you want - a dictionary.

If you were providing a dictionary with matching keys you could do

```
payload = request.get_json()
return openai.ChatCompletion.create(**payload)
```

Otherwise, parse each key manually

```
payload = request.get_json()
return openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model=payload["model"], 
    messages=payload["messages"]
)
```

Also, Flask prefers you return text / rendered HTML, rather than a direct Python object

Comment: How do you achieve the "not needed" argument functionality?

Comment: @EnderBender What do you get from `type(request.get_json())`? It sounds like somehow you have a string, but that shouldn't be possible.

Comment: @CrazyChucky it returns <class 'str'> because I used json.dumps in my request body. I have changed that and it works now, thank you all for your help.